# Is Apache server part of default installation?

Tags: apache2, default-programs

I have a running apache2 server on my computer.

As I do not use it as a server, can I remove it safely (to save RAM, boot-up time, etc.) or is it still useful (like part of Ubuntu default installation)?

Comment: If you dont use it you can remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache is not part of default Ubuntu installation, you had to install it manually. If you don't use it, you should remove it.

Comment: Thanks ! I started using Ubuntu three years ago with 7.10 and use 10.10 now (no new installation since then, only upgrades) and frankly, I couldn't remember if I ever installed apache or not ^^